# How do I make my own add on?

Tags: modeling, add-on, 3d-printing

This is going to be a very specific question so for some context- roughly 2 years ago I started learning to how use blender for my job

(I'm a dental technician and my boss wanted to start using the "blender for dental" add on to turn scans our customers send us into printable models as a cheaper alternative to getting them made by a 3rd party)

And i've grown to really enjoy Blender tho by no means do i consider myself an expert.

Now to the actual question- we always struggle finding suitable models (at least upper and lower jaws that actually fit together) for our apprentices to practice on- you give one out, say "put it back where you took it from" and it disappears forever.

So recently i got the idea that we could bypass this problem if i made an add on for blender where they can design their own models specific to what they need, print them and they'd all always fit together.

Stumps in the front, fully toothed in the side, or even complete blanks for total prosthetics

The image below is obviously edited and i didn't use any actual dental models yet just in case it's not possible afterall so i don't waste too much time but basically how i thought it could work is- first you generate a complete toothless upper and lower jaw- than you pick what you want the toothed version to look like

B- blank

S- stump

T- tooth

Then you click to generate it and the add on loads whichever part you chose from your library onto the model and idealy applies a boolean union modifier in the process..

Now please be realistic with me here- is this even possible for someone like me? If yes- are there any good tutorials that can show me how to do this or does anyone have any advice where to begin with this?

If you made it this far and read all of my rambling thank you so much, I truly appreciate it <3 :)
[image]

Comment: This is a Q&A site to help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons only. Having said that, the simple answer is: If you've never written an addon or used python before it's highly unlikely that you'd be able to do what you want without a great deal of research and thorough understanding of both addons and python.

Comment: just to clarify: the user interface (the buttons) is a mockup/an edited image? Or is it already created by Python code?

Comment: I think your question (Q) is actually 3 Qs. I highly recommend editing your Q and splitting it to create 3 or 4 focused Qs each to address one specific problem. This will make your Qs more helpful for other users that have the same or a similar problem. Ask the Qs in a common but focused way, with a short description & an example, and a few keywords. Tell the readers what you try to achieve, what you have tried, what doesn't work, and where you are stuck/need help/about the problem. Then more people will find your Qs by the keywords & you will get more attention, feedback & answers (A) :-)

Comment: I see here 3 questions: The first Q (non-technical) is what you have asked in the title **Q1)** Can someone with no programming skill create a Blender add-on? **Q2)** is about the UI. There are plenty of examples here about how to create a *panel*, *buttons* that call an *operator* & how to create *radio buttons*. But I haven't found something like "How to update properties of multiple objects by a list of Radio Buttons?" **Q3)** is about the button action/operator like "How to pick an object from a collection and place it at a given position with Python" or "How to create a script that ..."

Comment: (The *italic* words in the previous comment are keywords) **Q4)** bonus question ;-) might be about *3D Printing*, like "How to make a model of multiple objects/mesh parts printable?" (boolean op/remesh?). The answers of Q2-Q4 will help people who want to create a completely different add-on but that is kinda the same as your add-on. Something like a traffic light generator (lights=tooths, the housing of the traffic light=jaw) or a car generator with customizable wheels and rims (wheels=tooths, car=jaw). The answers of Q2-Q4 will answer your first Q ;-)

Comment: About **Q1)** I agree with John Eason but it also depends on the complexity of the add-on. Your add-on is rather simple. You don't have to deal with mesh data & there is no vector math needed. There are many examples/add-on templates and if you get an answer to Q2 and Q3 and look for more code snippets then you can "Frankenstein" it => modify and put it all together to create the add-on. It helps to know the basics of programming (if...then...else, loops, data types) & Blender's API (UI elements, EnumProperties, etc). With keywords, you'll find many examples on stackoverflow.com & here.
.